# if conditional in sidebar plugin Password content shortcode

Tags: php, sidebar

I have this code [][/] on page and work perfectly! so i want now if i can in sidebar check if the form is properly completed on the page and then will echo some word in sidebar. for example something like this in sidebar:

```
if (isset($_POST['csp_submit'])) {
if ($_POST['csp_input'] == $password AND $password != '') {
echo 'password is corect and echo some words';
}
else
{
echo 'password is wrong';
}
}
else
{
echo 'you must enter pasword on page';
}
```

https://wordpress.org/plugins/password-content-shortcode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways you can do that,

1. You can write a new short code for e.g [check_sumbit] and then use it in side bar, and that short should check if form is submitted correctly
2. You can use php code as you mentioned in your question using some plugins that allow php code in widgets. For e.g.
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/

Comment: check if I entered something or not - this is ok. but if you enter the right password get that password is not correct. but it is correct

Comment: i solve i write another functions it is not hard as i mind :) thanx for suggestions